# Mongo to Postgres migration - Convert mongo hexa Id field to shorter integer

Tags: mongodb, postgresql, int, migration, bigint

Am migrating MongoDB to postgres.

Thanks to postgres JSON , which makes it easy to move nested documents as JSON. But the problem starts in migrating the "ID" field.

Mongo generates a large hexadecimal number `56c4100560b2d8308f4bde21`

I tried converting this to BigInt and unfortunately it is out of range `26397231623443762880753094891`

1. The ID cannot be re-generated as its been interlinked between the documents everywhere.
2. String cannot be used as ID field, as am moving to Postgres + JPA ,and I will be using auto generate sequence moving forward.

Is there  any way, I can cut short this hexadecimal to a shorter version of Int or BigInt , at the same time, I should maintain the uuiqueness

I tried taking modulus, but it brings in repetition

Comment: you could use the same hex as bytea I suppose

Comment: ID should int/bigint. Unfortunately I cannot change it

Comment: then you probably will need some mapping. Like create a bigint sequence to use as ID and migrating data save map old_hex -> new_int somewhere

Comment: Usually, these fields are migrated to be a [`uuid` field](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-uuid.html) (this is usually well supported in JPA implementations: e.g. you can generate random UUIDs more than one way) -- when you want to use the original value as a `bigint` f.ex. (and want to use an auto-incrementing value onwards) there is a problem: if a small value appears in your existing rows, your solution will start rejecting some `INSERT` upon reaching it.

Comment: See f.ex. http://stackoverflow.com/q/41502698/1499698 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/244243/1499698

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your best option is to migrate MongoDB's `ObjectId` fields to PostgreSQL's [`uuid`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-uuid.html) columns. Note that UUID has more bytes in it, so you'll need to pad the values.

See more on that:

- [POSTGRESQL:autoincrement for varchar type field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41502698/postgresqlautoincrement-for-varchar-type-field)

If you really want to use `bigint`s, you have two options:

**1. Create completely new values**

1. create your schema (with tables, constraints, etc.)

   - in this schema, use `text` / `varchar` for your `ObjectId` values (for now)
2. create [foreign keys](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-FK) for all your relations, with `ON UPDATE CASCADE` for all `ObjectId` columns.
3. create [sequences](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createsequence.html) for all tables, which have `ObjectId` columns.
4. update `ObjectId` columns (while they are still `text` / `varchar`), with:

   ```
   UPDATE table_name
   SET    object_id_col = nextval('table_name_object_id_col_seq')::text
   ```

   (This will propagate the changes to referencing tables, because foreign keys were set up earlier.)
5. drop foreign keys
6. change your column types of these `ObjectId` columns to `bigint`
7. alter your sequences to be `OWNED BY` the table column
8. alter tables to use `nextval('table_name_object_id_col_seq')` as default values
9. re-add foreign keys

This method is guaranteed to never cause duplicate values during migration. And the sequence can be used to create new values for the primary keys.

**2. Use your original values in some way**

Truncation will cause information loss, so you *may* end up with duplicated values, no matter what method you will try. However, you can reduce the chance of this by using f.ex. bitwise `XOR` (usually the `#` operator in PostgreSQL) instead of modulus.

With this function f.ex. you can use your original values as:

1. start with `0` (or with some other, fix starting value)
2. with each iteration, use **N** number of the least significant bits from input
3. calculate result as `<the_previous_result> # <value_from_2.>`
4. continue at 2. when there is more, unused bits (input should be the old input but the **N** least significant bits)

Here is an SQL function, which does that:

```
create or replace function hex_xor(p_hex text, p_bits int default 64, p_default bigint default 0)
  returns bigint
  language sql
  immutable
as $func$
  with recursive r as (
      select ('x' || p_hex)::varbit h, p_default r, 0 i
    union all
      select case
               when bit_length(h) <= p_bits then varbit ''
               else substring(h for bit_length(h) - p_bits)
             end,
             r # case
               when bit_length(h) <= p_bits then h::bit(64)::bigint
               else substring(h from bit_length(h) - p_bits + 1 for p_bits)::bigint
             end,
             i + 1
      from   r
      where  bit_length(h) > 0
  )
  select   r
  from     r
  order by i desc
  limit    1
$func$;
```

This assumes that the `p_hex` parameter is really in hex format & the `p_bits` parameter is never greater than `64`.

**But** if you just use this as is, you may end up later, with conflicting values upon `INSERT`. What you can do is f.ex. to use:

```
select -hex_xor('56c4100560b2d8308f4bde21', 63)
```

upon migration. This way migrated `ObjectId`s will always be negative values & later generated primary keys (f.ex. from a sequence) will always be positive.

http://rextester.com/RCVFN77368